# How do write a templated free function depending on return type

Tags: c++, templates, return-type-deduction

I have a problem related to type deduction from a function return value.

First, some context, to show what I expect.
Say I have this function template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 foo( T2 t )
{
    T1 a = static_cast<T1>(t); // dummy conversion,
    return a;                  // just there to use t
}
```

then, this does not build, because return type can't be used for type deduction:

```
int a;
float v1 = foo(a);
char  v2 = foo(a);
```

But if I add the requested type, then it's okay:

```
int a;
auto v1 = foo<float>(a);
auto v2 = foo<char>(a);
```

Now my problem. I have a class, that provides a getter to some data:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
   T data;
   template<typename U>
   U get() { return static_cast<U>(data); }  // dummy code, returns an 'U'
};
```

User code can fetch the data with this (builds fine):

```
MyClass<int> m;
auto v3 = m.get<float>();
```

But I want to provide to user code a second way to access the data, by using a free function, so one can write:

```
MyClass<int> m;
auto v4 = ff_get<float>(m);
```

The question is:
**How do I write `ff_get()`?**

I tried:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 ff_get( T2 t )
{
    return t.get<T1>();
}
```

But this will not build, although it seems to me is uses the same syntax as the `foo` call above. So second part of the question is: why does this fail?

(see [live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0980b40b644985c))

Comment: Wow, that was quick (59 seconds before duped)! I had that one in my favorites, but I didn't see the relation. Modern GCC now usually tells you when you forget the 'typename".

Comment: Not sure I understand why, but @molbdnilo just deleted his answer, so, in case, he/she explained that all you need it so replace `return t.get<T1>();` with `return t.template get<T1>();`

Comment: if you click the link above you will be taken to a similar question and answers that explain it

Comment: If one is to treat your question as purely about the syntax of applying the `template` at the appropriate place, then the duplicate explains that fine. I have expanded my answer to address the question implied in your question title, and explained how using conversion can address the question you asked about `ff_get`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, thanks, got that ;-) I just not fully agree on the "similar" aspect, but... whatever. The answer over there is indeed a valuable tutorial.

Comment: @jxh Agree, thanks for your efforts, I appreciate, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Convert the return type rather than deduce it

You can create a conversion proxy object for your return type. This moves the return type deduction into a template conversion operation instead.

```
template <typename T>
struct foofoo {
    T t_;
    foofoo (T t) : t_(t) {}
    template <typename U>
    operator U () const { return static_cast<U>(t_); }
};

template <typename T>
foofoo<T> foo( T t )
{
    return foofoo<T>(t);
}
```

Applied to `MyClass`, your getter could be implemented similarly:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
   T data;
   foofoo<T> get() { return foofoo<T>(data); }
};
```

And then, this code would work just fine:

```
MyClass<int> m;
float v3 = m.get();
```

#### Deduce the return type of the getter

Now, to implement `ff_get`, it is mostly a trivial function implementation, except that the return type is now deduced from the `get` method itself. In C++11, you would use the *trailing return type* syntax.

```
template <typename T>
auto ff_get (T t) -> decltype(t.get())
{
    return t.get();
}
```

Starting from C++ 14, you can drop the trailing return type altogether, since there is no ambiguity in the return type.

```
template <typename T>
auto ff_get (T t)
{
    return t.get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but this sound a bit more verbose than the other answer.

Comment: The advantage is that your original assignments work now from your original example.

Comment: @kebs this is a whole different approach. It lets you emulate deduction from the return type. You can now write `int x = get(m);`

Comment: Ah, yes, sure, didn't see that point, but I agree it could be valuable.